# ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT put NAME

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am using `Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT` for inserting/editing contact to mobile phone. 
However, I put a `ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME` to bundle for case when user want to insert a new contact. But the name is inserted also when user choose edit contact (the old name is rewrited) ... is there some FLAG or something how to prevent this behavior ?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT);
                intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
                intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME,
                        u.getName());
                intent.putExtra(INTENT_KEY_FINISH_ACTIVITY_ON_SAVE_COMPLETED,
                        true);
                startActivityForResult(intent, ADD_CONTACT);
```